# Android onCreate() Method called twice when device rotated. (ICS)

Tags: android

I'm developing on an android tablet application and I have to manage application orientation. I got a problem that every time when I rotate the device onCreate() will be called.

I fixed this problem on Honeycomb (3.1) by set this line in Manifest.xml file at the activity tag and it works well.

```
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

But this problem came back again when I test my app on ICS Tablet. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are targeting an `API level > 13` you have to add the `screenSize` flag as reported in the doc:

```
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: This worked for me as well.  What does screen size have to do with restarting the activity?

Comment: Thanks a lot Blackbelt, not only this problem, your answer fixed 2-3 problems I had, and was suffering since a day. (y)

Comment: unbelievable... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`onCreate()` will always be called because when orientation changes the Activity is always recreated. There is nothing wrong with that. You should implement proper behaviour for this or disable the possibility of changing the orientation by adding orientation=horizontal to manifest for instance

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for your reply. My problem is I have EditText in my layout when I input text and rotate device my inputted text will be disappeared. Some of my activities I set a custom thread in there and display my custom Progress Dialog , when I rotate it my custom thread will be called twice and my Progress Dialog will be disappeared too.

Comment: Because Activity is recreated its whole lifecycle is restarted. You should use saveInstanceState to persist the edited information. "Because of this, you should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such as user edits) to storage. In addition, the method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be re-created. "

Answer (score 0):

> **Caution:** Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must declare **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize**". However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html