# onCreate were called twice after implementing setRequestedOrientation

Tags: android, eclipse, screen-orientation

I have a problem here where i need to display a data from a database and view it in my app in a form of table. Everything went well but since the table column is quite long(due to the data received from the database), i decided to set the orientation to landscape for easy view (i guess). After implementing this code,

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

The onCreate() function got called twice. I knew it got called twice since ive included the log.i. All of my log.i got called twice.  My log should display this:

```
03-19 14:13:53.401: I/loop check(30510): loop
03-19 14:13:54.112: I/jObjLength(30510): 5
03-19 14:13:54.112: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work0
03-19 14:13:54.162: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work1
03-19 14:13:54.162: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work2
03-19 14:13:54.172: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work3
03-19 14:13:54.172: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work4
```

But instead, it shows this:

```
03-19 14:30:12.801: I/loop check(30510): loop
03-19 14:30:12.921: I/jObjLength(30510): 5
03-19 14:30:12.921: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work0
03-19 14:30:12.931: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work1
03-19 14:30:12.941: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work2
03-19 14:30:12.951: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work3
03-19 14:30:12.951: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work4
03-19 14:30:12.981: I/loop check(30510): loop
03-19 14:30:13.042: I/jObjLength(30510): 5
03-19 14:30:13.042: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work0
03-19 14:30:13.042: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work1
03-19 14:30:13.052: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work2
03-19 14:30:13.052: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work3
03-19 14:30:13.062: I/JSON(30510): jsonObj = work4
```

This happen after i implement the setRequestedOrientation. Can anybody explain why thiss is happening and what are the solution for this. Thanks

heres my onCreate class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    Log.i("loop check", "loop");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_listing);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    tblLay = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblLayout);

    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    jObj = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

    txtOrderN = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txtCabinetN = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txtAssignP = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txtActualP = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txtStatS = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    String jsonObj;

    for (int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
        jsonObj = "work";
        jsonObj = jsonObj + i;

        try {
            tblRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i("JSON", "jsonObj = " + jsonObj);
            txtOrderN.setText(jObj.getJSONObject(jsonObj).getString(
                    "orderN"));
            txtCabinetN.setText(jObj.getJSONObject(jsonObj).getString(
                    "cabinetN"));
            txtAssignP.setText(jObj.getJSONObject(jsonObj).getString(
                    "assignP"));
            txtActualP.setText(jObj.getJSONObject(jsonObj).getString(
                    "actualP"));
            txtStatS.setText(jObj.getJSONObject(jsonObj).getString("statS"));
            txtOrderN = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            txtCabinetN = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            txtAssignP = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            txtActualP = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            txtStatS = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

            tblRow.addView(txtOrderN);
            tblRow.addView(txtCabinetN);
            tblRow.addView(txtAssignP);
            tblRow.addView(txtActualP);
            tblRow.addView(txtStatS);
            tblLay.addView(tblRow);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error " + e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("Error ", "" + e);
        }

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zeta.workorder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.zeta.workorder.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.zeta.workorder.WorkListingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_work_listing" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you also have to declare the orientaion in your activity also in your manifest file.also setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); use this after you set the contentview.

Comment: will you show me how to declare it on android manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
in your manifest file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zeta.workorder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="com.zeta.workorder.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.zeta.workorder.WorkListingActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_work_listing"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
</activity>
```

Comment: This works! i just added android:screenOrientation="landscape" at the manifest and remove the setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) from my onCreate class. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just add property
`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in manifiest in `<activity>` tag

Source : [Android onCreate() Method called twice when device rotated. (ICS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636075/android-oncreate-method-called-twice-when-device-rotated-ics)