# Android loosing reference after orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

i have a MainActivity that contains my fragments, and i have implemented an interface MainView that main activity implements it. Also i created an abstract base fragment and all my fragments extends from it. I declare MainView in basefragment. When i add fragments, i am setting MainView onAttach of the base fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            this.mainView = (MainView) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.getClass() + " must implement MainView");
        }
    }
```

Then i am calling MainViews method from fragments like

```
public void showProgress() {
        if (mainView != null)
            mainView.showProgress();
    }
```

Everything works fine at first but when i rotate the device, i am again set the main view `onAttach` but when i call the showProgress, i see mainView null. I am little bit confused why i am getting mainView null. And also i declare `SwipeRefreshLayout` in base fragment, and again after rotation change i am pulling the layout, progess is showing but `swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()` is false. So i can not the hide swipeRefreshLayout progress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android onCreate() Method called twice when device rotated. (ICS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636075/android-oncreate-method-called-twice-when-device-rotated-ics)

Answer (score 0):

In your menifest, in activity tag add below line

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Hey, thank you it worked :D Could you please explain the logic?

Comment: please read documentation -- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html